# Get the job link in groovy script

Tags: jenkins

We need to update few job configurations accross all jobs and there are several instances of Jenkins running for multiple projects. We need to udpate SCM database path and the SCM password.

I am able to do the database path, but for password there is no set method. So to overcome this, I am just trying to print the link of the job for which we need to update the password. I could not find an API for job link.

Could you please help me out here, or suggest a better solution to update the password?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
import hudson.model.*
jenkins = Hudson.instance
for (item in jenkins.items){
    println jenkins.getRootUrl()+item.getUrl()
}
```

Tried this in script console. Lists all jobs absolute URLs. You just need to add the logic to get your jobs list

Comment: thanks Yuri, but is there a way to make sure the link is clickable? right now it comes as a plain text

Comment: create a job with build step "Execute system Groovy script" and paste this code. You will get a clickable links in the job cosnole

Comment: It can be simplified like this: `println jenkins.rootUrl+item.url` -- Groovy automatically looks for getter/setter function, when using property syntax.